# How can one get a ContextMenuStrip to show on left click of a NotifyIcon?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon, contextmenustrip

I have a ContextMenuStrip assigned to a NotifyIcon and this works with the right click fine.

How may I wire up the mouse-click event to tell the NotifyIcon to show its ContextMenuStrip?

```
private void taskbarIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Button)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Left:
            // What could I use here?
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use the following code:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
   MethodInfo mi = typeof(NotifyIcon).GetMethod("ShowContextMenu", 
            BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    mi.Invoke(taskbarIcon, null);
}
```

[Here's a good thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8de03b21-e144-4614-96cd-d382c2a2fbe9/) about the subject at MSDN site.

Comment: Thank you heaps for your quick response! It worked perfectly.

Comment: Does using System.Reflection in cases like this cause any performance penalties?